# Custom keyboard crash in iOS10

Tags: crash, uitextfield, ios10

The UITextField.inputView is my custom input view.
I had get the crash from users and can't reproduce the issue. 
The flowing is crash log.

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x1e9a364a
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:

1. CoreFoundation                      0x1e9a364a _CFRelease + 1366
2. UIKit                               0x23a684ef -[UIKBTree setObject:forProperty:] + 209
3. UIKit                               0x23b32ce7 -[UIKBTree zipGeometries:attributes:] + 1069
4. UIKit                               0x23b306e1 -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar setKeyplaneName:] + 4721
5. UIKit                               0x23a6ab8f -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar setShift:] + 297
6. UIKit                               0x23a6a837 -[UIKeyboardImpl notifyShiftState] + 85
7. CoreFoundation                      0x1e9a1485 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 21
8. CoreFoundation                      0x1e99f701 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 283
9. CoreFoundation                      0x1e99fa59 __CFRunLoopRun + 745
10. CoreFoundation                      0x1e8ef073 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
11. CoreFoundation                      0x1e8eee81 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
12. GraphicsServices                    0x20097bfd GSEventRunModal + 157
13. UIKit                               0x23a8fccf -[UIApplication _run] + 575
14. UIKit                               0x23a8a401 UIApplicationMain + 151
15. MyApplication                       0x000b134b main (main.m:16)
16. ???                                 0x1e0ba50b 0x0 + 0

Do there are anyone has same issue?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a reason/solution ?

Comment: Not yet, can't find the reason why the issue happen.

Comment: I am also experiencing this crash and am unable to replicate. I believe it has something to do with custom keyboard accessory views.  My logs indicate that that the app is running for these users quite a while prior to the crash happening.  Could it be memory related? is there a new necessary step when adding an accessory view?

Comment: There seems may be a system memory issue. We using the custom keyboard of input view, sometimes the system still layout the system keyboard and will throw an except. There should using the input view in my app. I'm not using the accessory view, but input view.

Comment: Ahh good point LiuPengBty.  I also use the InputView somewhere. I will keep trying to debug with that functionality in mind.

Comment: I get crash reports with this backtrace too, but only for iPad 4s running iOS 10.

Comment: @SteveShepard Mine also all appear to be iPad 4 on iOS 10.